Can anyone check my understanding of Verb stem+あげる/切る／通す／終わる　and てしまう
As far as i understand, those words pretty much means "doing something completely" but each have its own nuance. I'll use the word　読む　for conjugating as an example.
1.読み終わる
　This one is just saying that you finished reading, emphasize the end of the verb.
2.読みあげる
I don't really get this one, あげる is the most tricky one for me.
3．読み通す
This mean that you read through (something), but you might not read all the letters, you might skip the unneccesary information. But basically you read through the thing.
4．読み切る
This mean you really read the whole thing, in the sense of you read every character that was written.
5．読んでしまう
This mean you finished the read and it can't be help or you might regret after reading it
Am I understand those nuance correctly or am I missing something. I'm pretty sure there are more nuance to it and I wanna know, especially 通す／切る/あげる

Related: 動作の完成を表す言葉について

I am not a Japanese grammar expert but just a native Japanese speaker.
1.読み終わる
　I understand the same as you do.
2.読みあげる
When 読み上げる is used in this meaning, I thinik it has a nuance of reading a long book or difficult book to read(I feel it has a nuance of achievement)
Note: the most common usage of 読み上げる is "read out loud".
3．読み通す
I understand the same as you do.
4．読み切る
I'm not sure that this has a nuance of " in the sense of you read every character that was written.". For me, this one is close to 読み上げる and has a nuance of achievement(I have a slight feeling that 読み上げる and 読み切る might be interchangeable.)
5．読んでしまう
I think the meaning you think is ok.
But I suspect that this phrase doesn't have a nuance of read a whole books like others. So we can use this with other expressions above like「読み切ってしまう/読み上げてしまう/読み通してしまう」(most of the time, I think this use in the past tense like 読み切ってしまった). This emphasize that the person can't be help but reading the whole book or they regret it.
